# Java Calendar/Date Issue while adding Month

Tags: java

If we add 1 month in current date(Fri May 31 18:33:00 IST 2013) it yields:

**Sun Jun 30 18:33:00 IST 2013**

If we subtract 1 month it yields:

**Thu May 30 18:33:00 IST 2013**

Is it a bug OR can anyone provide the reasoning?

Please find the code for same:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance()
System.out.println(c1.getTime());
c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println(c1.getTime());
c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(c1.getTime());
```

Output

```
Fri May 31 18:33:00 IST 2013
Sun Jun 30 18:33:00 IST 2013
Thu May 30 18:33:00 IST 2013
```

Comment: whats wrong in output? its giving proper dates

Comment: This is the expected behavior. When you add 1 month it cannot go to June 31th since it does not exists, so it goes to June 30th. When you subtracts it goes to May 30th, because it is allowed.

Comment: i think he thinks that 31.05 + 1 month should be 01.07 or something like that since there is no 31.06.

Answer (score 6):

The changing of the day of month is the expected behaviour, documented here, as "Add rule 2": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

> **add(f, delta)** adds delta to field f. This is equivalent to calling set(f, get(f) + delta) with two adjustments:
>
> > **Add rule 1.** The value of field f after the call minus the value of field f before the call is delta, modulo any overflow that has occurred in field f. Overflow occurs when a field value exceeds its range and, as a result, the next larger field is incremented or decremented and the field value is adjusted back into its range.
> >
> > **Add rule 2**. If a smaller field is expected to be invariant, but it is impossible for it to be equal to its prior value because of changes in its minimum or maximum after field f is changed or other constraints, such as time zone offset changes, then its value is adjusted to be as close as possible to its expected value. A smaller field represents a smaller unit of time. HOUR is a smaller field than DAY_OF_MONTH. No adjustment is made to smaller fields that are not expected to be invariant. The calendar system determines what fields are expected to be invariant.

With these rules in place, there's no way to keep the day of month if you add 1 month, followed by adding -1 months.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a feature and is documented (sorry being picky here, but did you actually read the docs before asking?). Read the `Field Manipulation` sectione in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) about the `add()` method. Relevant part:

> If a smaller field is expected to be invariant, but it is impossible
>   for it to be equal to its prior value because of changes in its
>   minimum or maximum after field f is changed or other constraints, such
>   as time zone offset changes, then its value is adjusted to be as close
>   as possible to its expected value.
>
> Example: Consider a GregorianCalendar originally set to August 31,
>   1999. Calling add(Calendar.MONTH, 13) sets the calendar to September 30, 2000. Add rule 1 sets the MONTH field to September, since adding
>   13 months to August gives September of the next year. Since
>   DAY_OF_MONTH cannot be 31 in September in a GregorianCalendar, add
>   rule 2 sets the DAY_OF_MONTH to 30, the closest possible value.
>   Although it is a smaller field, DAY_OF_WEEK is not adjusted by rule 2,
>   since it is expected to change when the month changes in a
>   GregorianCalendar.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct as it is designed.

When you add one month from May 31st you get June 30th (the last day of the month).

When you subtract one month from June 30th you get May 31st (one month earlier).

The calculation are done when you get the time with `getTime()`. Therefore I don't see any bug here.

Answer (score 0):

Update for the modern age, using the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes including `Calendar`.

### Time zone

Define your time zone. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). I am guessing you meant India time by `IST`, but perhaps Irish Standard Time or other?

```
final ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" );
```

The `ZonedDateTime` class represents a moment on the timeline adjusted into a particular time zone.

```
final ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of ( 2013, 5, 31, 18, 33, 0, 0, z );
```

### `plusMonths` | `minusMonths`

```
final ZonedDateTime zdtMonthPlus = zdt.plusMonths ( 1 );
final ZonedDateTime zdtMonthMinus = zdtMonthPlus.minusMonths ( 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
System.out.println ( "zdtMonthPlus.toString(): " + zdtMonthPlus );
System.out.println ( "zdtMonthMinus.toString(): " + zdtMonthMinus );
```

We see the same behavior as with the legacy `Calendar` class. When adding a month from May 31 there is no June 31st so it falls back to the last day of the month, June 30. When subtracting from June 30, the class tries to match the same day-of-month, so it uses May 30.

> zdt.toString(): 2013-05-31T18:33+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
>
> zdtMonthPlus.toString(): 2013-06-30T18:33+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
>
> zdtMonthMinus.toString(): 2013-05-30T18:33+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

### `plus( Duration)` | `minus( Duration )`

If you want another behavior, use another approach to your code. For example, if by "month" you really mean “30 days of generic 24-hour days (ignoring anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time)”, then add/subtract durations of 30 days.

```
Duration thirtyDays = Duration.ofDays( 30 );  // 30 days of generic 24-hour length. Ignoring anomalies such as DST. Ignoring calendar months.
final ZonedDateTime zdtMonthPlusDuration = zdt.plus ( thirtyDays );
final ZonedDateTime zdtMonthMinusDuration = zdtMonthPlusDuration.minus ( thirtyDays );
```

> thirtyDays.toString(): PT720H
>
> zdtMonthPlusDuration.toString(): 2013-06-30T18:33+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
>
> zdtMonthMinusDuration.toString(): 2013-05-31T18:33+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).